# QoS bandwidth throttling not working

Tags: php

I am using the following code to control the bandwidth usage through download link. Here is the code that i am using with implementation of [QOS Bandwidth Throttle PHP](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6709-PHP-Limit-the-speed-of-files-served-for-download.html)

```
// create new config
$config = new ThrottleConfig();
// enable burst rate for 30 seconds
$config->burstTimeout = 30;
// set burst transfer rate to 50000 bytes/second
$config->burstLimit = 10000;
// set standard transfer rate to 15.000 bytes/second (after initial 30 seconds of burst rate)
$config->rateLimit = 15000;
// enable module (this is a default value)
$config->enabled = true;

// start throttling
$x = new Throttle($config);


header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$zipname."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$zipname."\"");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($directory_location . '/' . $zipname));
```

I am getting corrupted file, no actual size(4MB) and i get approximate (2KB) size. And if i use the `readfile()` function then i didn't found the throttle class working with `readfile()` :(

Can anyone please tell me, what wrong i have done here?

Comment: Well, what exactly happens?

Comment: @Pekka웃 i am sorry i forgot to mention the exact problem, I have updated my problem in bottom of the question.

Comment: Look inside the file. What does it contain?

Comment: @Pekka웃 i did, according to file i don't have to implement the `readfile()` function into the my main file, take a look on line `168` on http://pastebin.com/6FfeNx74, `ob_start()` returns the buffered data, here is the sample example i found on the file. http://pastebin.com/u097yELu

Comment: No, did you look into the broken file? It most likely contains PHP error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$x = new Throttle($config);
$handle = fopen("yourfile.zip", "rb");
while (!feof($handle)) {
  echo fread($handle, 8192);
  flush();
}
fclose($handle);
```

You can also try ob_flush() instead of flush().

Comment: i tried, Download working with this but its freeze all the other processes. Like: after click on download link, i redirected the page to somewhere else and now its redirect after download complete, not after click event :(